# How do I keep first 10 members and delete rest of a Redis sorted set?

Tags: redis, sortedset

I want to keep the result of my last 10 queries in Redis sorted set. I use timestamps as the score. I need to keep top 10 members by score and delete the rest. I basically need `ZREMRANGEBYREVSCORE` or `ZREMRANGEBYREVRANK` but these commands do not exist. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a workaround with using negative scores with zremrangebyrank. I am not sure this is the right way but works for me.

```
counter = 0;
// temp data
setInterval(async () => {
    counter += 1;
    val = (new Date()).toString() + " " + counter;
    score = -1 * (new Date() / 1000);
    res = await client.zaddAsync("myset", score, val)
}, 1000)

// remove other than top50
setInterval(async () => {
    res = await client.zremrangebyrankAsync("myset", 50, -1);
    console.log("myset zremrangebyrank" + " " + res + " " + val);    
}, 5000)

// log
setInterval(async () => {
    res = await client.zrangeAsync("myset", 0, 5);
    console.log(res);

    res = await client.zcardAsync("myset");
    console.log("myset zcard" + " " + res);      
}, 2000)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for

```
ZREMRANGEBYRANK yourset 0 -11
```

This will remove all elements from your sorted set, keeping top 10.

Answer (score 1):

The redis command [`ZPOPMIN`](https://redis.io/commands/zpopmin) pops out the minimum value or specified number of minimum values from the sorted set. However, it is supported only from version 5.0.0 which is not stable.

Comment: I need to keep top 10 members and delete all others. ZPOPMIN deletes number of members specified by command. I don't know how many should I delete in this scenario.

Comment: @roser137 Can you use [`ZCARD`](https://redis.io/commands/zcard) to get the cardinality of the sorted set and delete the members.

Comment: You can use `ZCARD` to get the total number of elements in the set, and `total number - 10` is the `COUNT` that you need to `ZPOPMIN`.

Comment: This involves two steps. Should I use pipelines to use this method without data loss?